# HIbernate SQL String

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria

I have a SQL command which I want to convert into Hibernate form .
I am currently not able to get the query for the same .

Sample is shown below

```
select * from event as e, 
(select ev.userUuid, ev.peerUuid, max(ev.updatedAt) as updatedAt 
from event as ev 
where ev.userUuid='cfdfabdc-89a5-4cfe-87f9-27bbe28b1ca6' 
and ev.type in('MONEY')  
group by ev.userUuid, ev.peerUuid) as latest 
 where latest.userUuid = e.userUuid 
 and latest.peerUuid = e.peerUuid 
 and latest.updatedAt = e.updatedAt 
order by e.updatedAt desc
```

Please help here.

Comment: you may also want to post your hibernate mapping, that is the Event class and the xml file containing <hibernate-mapping>, if you also have that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to get all records of given user, along  with the latest update date

```
select e.id, e.userUuid, e.peerUuid, ..., 
(select max(latest.updatedAt) from Event latest 
 where latest.userUuid = e.userUuid 
 and latest.peerUuid = e.peerUuid) as latestUpdatedAt
from Event e
where e.userUuid = :userUuid
and e.type in ('MONEY')  
group by e.userUuid, e.peerUuid
order by e.updatedAt
```

Or if you want to get only the latest record for given user, then you'd  apply `Query.setMaxResults()` on this HQL

```
select e.id, e.userUuid, e.peerUuid, ..., 
from Event e
where e.userUuid = :userUuid
and e.type in ('MONEY')  
group by e.userUuid, e.peerUuid
order by e.updatedAt desc
```

HQL subquery https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

Query.setMaxResults: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults(int)